# Having a different numbering for sections, subsections and theorems in appendix

Tags: theorems, appendix

I am using the `elsarticle` class.

It defines:

```
\def\appendixname{Appendix }
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \gdef\thefigure{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{figure}}%
  \gdef\thetable{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{table}}%
  \gdef\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}%
  \@addtoreset{equation}{section}%
  \gdef\theequation{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{equation}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\tmptocnumberline}{}{}
}
```

I use `amsmath` as following:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

Therefore, the following code produces the following output:

```
\appendix

\section{Test}

\subsection{test}

\begin{theorem}
    test
\end{theorem}
```

I would like to keep the `Appendix A` section title, but name subsections and theorems without the `Appendix` prefix (`A.1`, `A.2`, etc.).

If I use `\gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}%`, then the section title will not be correct.

Comment: If you are using the `elsarticle` as you are planning to publish with them then don't change their code, if you are using it just as a document class for a private or other file then hopefully someone can answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
  \renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}%
  \renewcommand\thesubsection{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{subsection}}%
  \renewcommand\thetheorem{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{theorem}}
```

Comment: If this works for you, please accept your own answer so that TeX SE knows that your question has been answered